# FOSUserBundle for admin and front end

Tags: symfony, authentication, admin, frontend, fosuserbundle

I am new to Symfony2. I am trying to use FOSUserBundle for user authentication.

Is it possible to use single FOSUserBundle for admin as well as front end section? If yes, then what changes i will need to make at script level?

What i want is:

```
1. if i access url http://localhost/symfony/admin/ then i should be redirected to http://localhost/symfony/admin/login if admin is not logged in and after successful login, i should be redirected to http://localhost/symfony/admin/

2. if i access url http://localhost/symfony/profile/ then i should be redirected to http://localhost/symfony/login if user is not logged in and after successful login, i should be redirected to http://localhost/symfony/profile/.
```

By default FOSUserBundle create user as administrator. So what change need to place in to let bundle create user role for front end automatically and admin role for admin section.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the authentication-success listener in your security configuration to have user's redirected to different pages after login depending on their roles.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020659/1832745) and maybe find some inspiration by looking at symfony's [DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020508/redirect-after-login-fos-user-bundle-symfony).

Further you will need to override the access-denied handler ( see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface) ) to have user's get redirected to different login pages depending on the url they're trying to access without being authenticated.

Comment: Ok, but configuration/changes would be required to keep two separate login page (one for admin and another for normal user of front end)?

Comment: if you want to use a bundle for your multi-user implementation you can give [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle) a try.