# Symfony with FosUserBundle - 2 different login success paths

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have 2 user roles in my application: `admin` and `member`. After a successful login, an `admin` user must be redirected to `/admin` and `member` must be redirected to `/catalog`.

Is this possible with Symfony and the FOSUserBundle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect after login fos user bundle symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020508/redirect-after-login-fos-user-bundle-symfony)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the login behaviour. It's nothing FOSUserBundle specific, it's a Symfony feature: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html#always-redirect-to-the-default-page

Another solution is a custom login authentication success handler. You can find an example here: https://gist.github.com/chalasr/69ad35c11e38b8cc717f